# Query database in MSSQL without linked server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an Access database that queries a SQL server using a connection string in the pass through description as follows:

```
ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=xxxx;APP=Microsoft Data Access Components;DATABASE=xxxx;Network=xxxx;TABLE=xxxx
```

How can I create a query in MSSQL to query the same database without having a linked server?

Following the response from robertdeniro I've tried the following:

```
SELECT top 10 *
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
   'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=ServerName;UID=UserID;PWD=xxx',
   'select @@ServerName') 

SELECT top 10 * 
FROM OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI',  
    'Data Source=serverName;Integrated Security=SSPI')  
    .TableToQuery
```

But I'm getting the following error messages:

> Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 SQL Server blocked access to
>   STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed
>   Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security
>   configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the
>   use of 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' by using sp_configure. For more
>   information about enabling 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', search for
>   'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' in SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: From Javier Jimenez Matilla : *I don't understand what is your question, how to query a mssql database? if so, using sql management studio. But, if you question the way of query access database from sql server, you need a driver MsJet and use a linked server to connect to access.*

Comment: @Selrac the question is unclear. What do you mean `create q query in MSSQL` - if the database is SQL Server, just write your query, stored procedure or whatever. If you want to query a different database on the same server, use a three-part name. If you want to query a *different* server, use a linked server. It's far easier than specifying the *same* data in each and every query that wants to access the remote server

Comment: You can use the [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql) function to retrieve data from a remote server BUT that's only for one-off ad-hoc queries. If you want to repeatedly call the same server, it makes much more sense to just create a Linked Server. The requirements are the same in both cases

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL SERVER functions OPENROWSET or OPENDATASOURCE. These functions let you specify database driver & connection settings for ad-hoc connections.

Your question doesn't give any info about how you plan to use this, so I can't give you an example.

You will be able to find the documentation on Microsoft's web site. Here's the current link [Rowset Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowset-functions-transact-sql)

If you need to enable ad-hoc queries:

```
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
reconfigure;
exec sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
reconfigure;
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain very well what I was looking for. Your answer guides me to what I'm looking for. I've edited the initial question with some tests with openrowset & opendatasource

Comment: I've updated my answer with steps you need to take to enable these functions if ad-hoc queries are not enabled. You'll need sysadmin privileges.